# ReCaptcha V2.0 IE 8 script error 5009 'Node' is undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am currently working getting the new recaptcha to work on a server application, however in IE edge running IE 8 compatibility mode the recaptcha breaks on 'recaptcha__en_gb.js, line: 29, column: 709' where the code is "script5009: 'Node' is undefined". Are there any work arounds for this, and does this affect actual IE 8 browsers and not just edge in IE 8 mode?

Comment: It worked until yesterday and now doesn't appear to work even on actual IE8. We noticed google.com updated to SHA2 certs yesterday but you can still visit that on IE8 on XP SP3 but recaptcha doesn't seem to work since then.

Comment: Thank you, my user base is mostly IE 8, and I don't have a computer old enough to run IE 8. So I just wrote compatibility code to use reCaptcha V 1.0 if the browsers are too old to run V 2.0. Hopefully they will fix this issue in the near future.

Comment: Care to share how that works? Though to be honest we've used this as the final nail in the IE8 coffin for our site. Luckily wasn't a huge proportion of our users and high time they upgraded :-)

Comment: Yeah the system was previously using the reCaptcha 1.0 library, so in all the places that we needed to use reCaptcha I simply used <!--[if lte IE 8]><![endif]--> around all of my required containers and bits of script for the version we were using previously

Comment: Weirdly it seems to be working for IE8 again even though it definitely wasn't before. Just noticed some people still using IE8 on our site and thought I'd double check and found it was working now. Though from IE11 (in IE8 mode) it's still complaining with above error.

Comment: Thanks for the information! although I am going to leave the compatibility code in for now, I will definitely have to look into getting an emulated environment so I can actually test IE 8 with the captcha